# SDK jar file downloading taking time in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jar, applet

I am having a strange issue, In our ASP.NET MVC application we are using jar files (Applet) , which will get downloaded in one of the first pages, In the QA environment these jar files were downloading with no time but in the production envirnment its these jars are taking more than a minute. I don't have much knowledge on the Bandwidth stuffs. 
Does anyone had experienced this issue ? 
Please advice what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If they are downloading from production successfully, just slower, then it is entirely a bandwidth issue.  The speed of download will depend on the available bandwidth and the physical/toplogical distance between the client and server.

If you aren't any "further" from your Production environment than QA, try a few raw tests by setting up a simple HTML page with links to files of varying sizes.  Test the download speed from your production server to ensure that the download speed from the HTML page is consistent with the download speed of your .jar files.

Comment: Thanks Dave for quick response, 
In QA those were downloading very quick , might be i need to check bandwidth for QA and production